# Нахождения квадратного корня

Tags: c#, c, c++

Собственно у меня есть два значения. Первое (a) - это значения, корень которого нужно найти. Второе (b) - это значения приближенное к ответу.
Например 10 и 3.
Если все правильно, то алгоритм нахождения корня следующий:

```
b = 0.5 ( b + a / b )
```

так продолжаем, вроде, пока разница между abs( b-b (привидущее) ) <= b-b.
(я точно не помню алгоритм. может он не правильный).

Помогите написать программу для нахождения квадратного корня числа без sqrt?
(любой язык)

Comment: Опишите полностью точный алгоритм сначала.

Comment: Правилами форума запрещено писать код за Вас. Напишите, что конкретно не вышло при реализации
з.ы. посредством гугла находится over 9000 кодов реализации...

Comment: @advoro b = 0.5 ( b + a / b ) продолжать пока модуль(b-b(предыдущее)) <= b-b(предыдущее). Вернуть b.

Comment: @andrei1610 "b" я откуда возьму?

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов я не понимаю как запомнить предыдущее значения, чтобы затем использовать ее в условии.

Comment: @alvoro a - само число. b - это значения, к которому стремится корень. Задается пользователем.

Comment: рекурсией, но это изврат
Ниже реализовано циклом while с условием (abs(b-bprev)<=b-b). bprev обновлять в конце цикла

Comment: Немного не в тему, но иногда может оказаться полезным на практике. 

Sqrt для integer. Результат тоже integer.

    {  // sqrt32()  найден где-то в интернете  
      unsigned int c = 0x8000;  
      unsigned int g = 0x8000;  
      unsigned int s = x; // это число, корень из которого вычисляем
    
      for(;;) {  
        if (g * g > s)  
          g ^= c;  
        c >>= 1;  
        if (c == 0)  
          break // результат это g;  
        g |= c;  
      }
    }

Просто выдернул из реального кода.

Comment: @avp Так, для общего развития, это "c" или что?

Comment: @alvoro, это из программы на Си (в С++ тоже будет работать).

Comment: А такой способ вычисления корня не подходит ?

    function sq(x) {
        return Math.exp(0.5 * Math.log(x));
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что я солидарен с [@Богдан Бессонов](/users/18377/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) . Это javascript

```
function getsqrt (num, sqrt) {
  sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  var sqrtPrev = sqrt;
  while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) <= (sqrt-sqrtPrev)) {
    if (sqrt === sqrtPrev) {
      return sqrt;
    }
    sqrtPrev = sqrt;
    sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
  }
  return sqrt;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, я только что заметил, что проход по циклу осуществляется только 1 раз. соответственно результат не правильный.

Comment: для получения более точного результата нужно убрать if

Comment: Вы правы. Затупил. Но if убирать не надо, сделайте так:

    function getsqrt (num, sqrt) {
      sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
      var sqrtPrev = sqrt;
      while (Math.abs(sqrt-sqrtPrev) <= (sqrt-sqrtPrev)) {
        sqrtPrev = sqrt;
        sqrt = 0.5*(sqrt+num/sqrt);
        if (sqrt === sqrtPrev) {
          return sqrt;
        }
      }
      return sqrt;
    }